# macOS Automator: Notification "click"-event

Tags: macos, notifications, applescript, macos-sierra, automator

I have created an Automator App with a Notification. I can provide "title", "subtitle" and "message". The Icon is the Icon from the automator bundle. That's good so far. But how can I handle the "click" event on the notification?

Or when I go the notification center and switch from "banner" to "alert", how can I handle the click on the "show" button? It seems that clicking the show button results in reopening the "referer". In my case a bash-Script.

What are the possibilities here?

System is macOS Sierra.

Thanks!

Comment: The underlying AppleScript runner engine is single-threaded and cannot handle the callbacks of `NSUserNotificationCenter`.

Comment: @vadian so there is no option I can get that to work? I am not forced to use the automator. I just want to get Notifications with title and text and an custom Icon. And now it would be nice to get the click event catched. Are there some external libraries that can handle this scenario? My base is a bash script from where I can trigger anything I want...

Comment: Not with AppleScript / Automator. You need a full-fledged Cocoa app which can be written in AppleScriptObjC.